# How to auto-aggregate all subprojects in a large SBT project without having to write a large "aggregate"?

Tags: scala, sbt

In my SBT project I have a root project that explicitly aggregates everything, like this:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "awesome_project",
    publishArtifact := false
  ).
  aggregate(
    some_project,
    some_other_project,
    a_cool_library,
    // lots and lots and lots more
  )
```

Since I explicitly have to add every project to the `aggregate` whenever a new one is added, is there a way to do it automatically? Currently I use a shell script for this which looks for all lines containing `lazy val` and `project`, outputs a list with a comma behind each name, and I copy-paste this list into the `aggregate`, but I figure there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: I think this solves your problem: Section _Default root project_ in https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it for project, but you can check if  reflection help you in this case:

```
protected val prjs = this.getClass.getDeclaredFields.flatMap { f =>
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.get(this) match {
      case p@Project => Some(f.asInstanceOf[Project])
      case _ => None
    }
  }.map(x => Project.projectToRef(x))
```

Comment: This will have problems if some project fields are lazy and not initialized yet. I also think you mean `case p: Project => Some(p)` in the 4th line.